# What are the mechanical effects of smoke grenades' smoke when using Auspex?

Tags: combat, chronicles-of-darkness-1e, weapons, vampire-the-requiem

Smoke grenades fill a place with obscuring white smoke. How does this affect a vampire using Auspex 1? Can they see through the smoke, or otherwise know what's happening (by hearing footsteps, etc.)?

Comment: "can he see what happens inside the smoke?" I'm guessing you're asking if the aura seen is distinguishable enough to recognize the movements  of what you're looking at? kind of like you're looking at them in infrared.

Comment: yes, like auspex 1 enables a vampire to see in pitch black darkness, does it also enables to see in smoke grenades smoke? btw you need at least auspex 2 to see aura, wrong?

Comment: Keep in mind, some smoke grenades create smoke via white phosphorus; in that case, seeing into the smoke may be the least of their worries!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Auspex I is Heightened Senses, i.e. increasing **one** of your five senses to supernatural levels (NOT aura perception). I personally always make my players define what sense they enhance.

So if it is anything other than Sight or Smell - use as normal. Hearing footsteps is perfectly fine. Smell would be overloaded, possibly leading to WP roll to avoid Frenzy, and Sight would be enhanced, but the smoke is still there. I'd say a kindred with heightened sight would be better off, but not as good as in pitch dark. They'll see silhouettes better, but they'll also see a lot of smoke, and it will distract them.